# Running two separate workers

Tags: android, worker, android-workmanager

I'm trying to run two separate Workers, When I start one worker I'm unable to start the other worker. I feel like I might be missing something to close the worker allowing me to start another worker.

Fragment

```
Constraints myConstrainst = new Constraints.Builder()
    .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.UNMETERED)
    .build();

OneTimeWorkRequest workerOne = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(WorkerOne.class)
    .setConstraints(myConstraints)
    .addTag("WorkerOne")
    .build();

OneTImeWorkRequest workerTwo = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(WorkerTwo.class)
    .setConstraints(myConstrains)
    .addTag("WorkerTwo")
    .build();

btnOne.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    WorkMananger.getInstance(getActivity()).enqueue(workerOne);
});

btnTwo.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    WorkManager.getInstance(getActivity()).enqueue(workerTwo);
});
```

WorkerOne

```
public class WorkerOne extends Worker {
    public WorkerOne(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Log.d("WorkerOne", "doWork " + i);
            SystemClock.sleep(1000);
        }
        return Result.success();
    }
}
```

WorkerTwo

```
public class WorkerTwo extends Worker {
    public WorkerTwo(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Log.d("WorkerTwo", "doWork " + i);
            SystemClock.sleep(1000);
        }
        return Result.success();
    }
}
```

Comment: what you get when you click btnTwo after btnOne? I mean what makes you sure that workerTwo doesn't start?

Comment: @Zain I have log tags in the doWork method that don't run. I've added the same for loop to Worker classes that I'm currently using.

Comment: Your code is working fine with me, both workers do their job, can you check if you are filtering logcat right, that both workers can be displayed, also try to put break points on both doWork() and debug to see if you get in both

Comment: @Zain that solved that problem, Is there a reason why I can't the workers more than once?

Comment: pardon, can you illustrate that more?

Comment: @Zain Say I press btnOne to run workerOne and wait for the work to finish. If I press btnOne a second time nothing happens.

Comment: please check updated answer with the new request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine with my test, both workers do their job,

As got from comments, filtering logcat not that right so you just get logs from one Worker while filtering out the other Worker's log.

This can be confirmed by debugging code with break points in both doWork().

> EDIT
>
> This is a request from comments not relevant to the question
>
> I press btnOne to run workerOne and wait for the work to finish. If I
> press btnOne a second time nothing happens

`OneTimeWorkRequest` is supposed to work only once, if you want to repeat the work you can instantiate the `OneTimeWorkRequest` object within the callback of your button, so it will be a new object with a new work request

```
btnOne.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    OneTimeWorkRequest workerOne = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(WorkerOne.class)
            .setConstraints(myConstraints)
            .addTag("WorkerOne")
            .build();

    WorkManager.getInstance(getActivity()).enqueue(workerOne);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be a case that your worker `Constraint` not match with current condition of your device. Please check your `Constraint`.

Comment: I don't think its an issue with myConstraint, it only has Network.UNMETERED on it. I've updated my question to include the builder for myConstraint.